# How could sein be the correct possessive in this case?

Tags: possessive-pronoun

In conversation with 2 native German speakers I wanted to say:

> The very sight of him rattled me.

So I said:

> Der bloße Anblick von ihm erschreckte mich.

Whereupon they called that sentence Umgangssprache and corrected it with:

> Sein bloßer Anblick erschreckte mich.

Their correction would seem to me to mean, "His very sight rattled me." And while this might be English that some use, I believe it improper in that it is not his sight but my sight of him that is being spoken about. So I would like to understand why Germans finds this superior to my first rendition. If anything I would think this would be more correct:

> Mein bloßer Anblick von ihm erschreckte mich.

Comment: You seem to assume that German *Anblick* and English *sight* have exactly the same meaning, but this is not the case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

English "sight" means "seeing something". It is a process. This is "Blick" in German.

> The eagle has the prey in **sight.**
> Der Adler hat die Beute im **Blick.**

But German "Anblick" is not the process of seeing something. It is the thing that is seen. So, *"Sein Anblick"* does not mean *"what he sees"* but *"what he looks like".* There is no English word for this. I think the closest existing English word is *appearance,* another option, but even less close is *picture.*

> Sein bloßer **Anblick** erschreckte mich.
> His mere **appearance** frightened me.

But English "appearance" describes not only how a person looks like, but also how they behave, how they move, the way of speaking, their smell etc. German *Anblick* means only that part of appearance, that can be captured in a picture.

In German there also is a word for *"appearance",* it is *"Erscheinung".*